# смена картинки при наведении на див

Tags: javascript, jquery

доброе время суток у меня есть див с классом test  и при наведении на див  надо сменить картинку  я попробовал написать на jquery но не могу понять где ошибка

```
if ($(".test") hover(handlerInOut(eventObject))){
  $(".test").attr("src", "img/Vector4.png");
```

}

Comment: Не понятно, что ты пытаешься проверить в данном условии и если test это див, то откуда у него src) Как вообще выглядит разметка? Мне кажется, то что ты хочешь можно реализовать при помощи css.

Comment: ето класи jq  второй рядок кода работает норм  я обращаюсь по класу в див и  в   ньом  меняю картинку ошибка в 1 строке кода  но спс вы помогли )))

Answer (score 0):

If не нужен. Плюс ко всему нарушен синтаксис.
У тебя должно быть что-то вроде этого.

```
$(".test").hover(function(){
  $(this).find('img').attr("src", "img/Vector4.png");
})
```

Смысл такой: при наведении указателя на элемент с классом "test" запускается функция-обработчик события, которая заменит у дочернего элемента
'img' атрибут src.

Comment: Стоит оговориться, что если внутри test лежит несколько img, то src поменяется у всех

Comment: спс меняетца но мне надо чтоб менялса на монет ховера и все если я не ошибаюсь надо написать handlerIn а потом handlerOut чтоб обратно поменять

Comment: @МішаКорольков В твоем случае разумнее было бы использовать css для этих целей. Создай в div'e две картинки, и скрой одну из них. На :hover скрываешь одну картинку при помощи display:none и показываешь другую

Comment: спс вы очень помогли